# Use system icon in SwiftUI with macOS as button

Tags: icons, swiftui, system

I like to use build-in icons for my buttons in SwiftUI, including a rectangle around the image. Simply like an ordinary button with a system icon.

But how can I use them? I can copy them as independend graphics in my project and then use

```
Image("MyIconName")
```

but I like to access them without making individual copy, like

```
Image( NSImage(NSImageNamePathTemplate) )
```

Any idea?

BTW: This does not belong to not support iOS icons, because NSImage offers these directly in macOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI on macOS, how to use custom image symbol on Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271693/swiftui-on-macos-how-to-use-custom-image-symbol-on-button)

Comment: I will check it, as soon as I'm able to implement this in my current project.

Comment: Yes, it works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is

```
Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.pathTemplateName)!)
```